# Why doesn't China reform its higher education sector/industry to keep its money and human capital at home?

Tags: china

- [Why So Many Chinese Students Come to America](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVCEvx8JCTQ)

Why doesn't China reform its higher education sector/industry to keep its money and human capital at home?

Comment: I think the entire goal of the Chinese higher education in the past decades has been to send their elite to the EU and the US to study and then bring this knowledge back. Most of the Chinese students in Germany e.g. will not stay in Germany.

Comment: Why pick on China? see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/36319/10902

Comment: @SolarMike, I am trying to understand China as part of my personal hobby.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum, _"I think the entire goal of the Chinese higher education in the past decades has been to send their elite to the EU and the US to study and then bring this knowledge back."_ How do they _send_ their elite out? Grabbing young kids in the middle of night and put them on planes?

Comment: Probably better for Politics.SE.

Comment: What hobby is this?